# How differentiate $.ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How i can get and differentiate $.ajax error?

I make a $.ajax, but it return **on console**:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" or "Uncaught ReferenceError: SSS is not defined"

Is possibility to differentiate between "SyntaxError" and "ReferenceError"?
Or similar?

I need make something like that:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "jsonp", 
     success: function (){       
     }
     error: function(){

         if(_______ == 'SyntaxError'){
         }
         if(_______ == 'ReferenceError'){
         }

      },
});
```

Is possible?

Sorry for my english, and noob question. :\

Comment: Start with not using `jsonp` here.

Comment: That's a parse error (of whatever is sent in the `jsonp` response is my guess), not an AJAX-related error.

Comment: This is actually a good question, and there is no simple answer for the general case, you can check `if(e instanceof SyntaxError){ ` and use the arguments of `error`. Good promise libraries like Bluebird can wrap `$.ajax` calls and let you use typed catch clauses.

Comment: The error handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests, so this has to be a local request, and the question then is, why are you expecting JSONP ?

Comment: Also, the error handler has three arguments that will tell you exactly what the error is, assuming the handler is called ?

Comment: I need to send one "GET" or "POST", cross-domain. 
And define if user is logged or not in the website.

And, if is logged, on console show: "Uncaught ReferenceError: SSS is not defined", but if user is not logged on website, the console show "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

And i think: How i can detect SyntaxError or ReferenceError.
But it, not return JSON. It return HTML. But is not possible make HTML/TEXT in cross-domain. But how browser can detect error and the $.Ajax call not?

Comment: It is not possible? :'(

Comment: It sure sounds like you're attempting to determine if the user is logged in depending on the side effect of an error based on your misuse of the `jsonp` type. This is, of course, a bad idea. Note, again, that reference and syntax errors are not AJAX related, but a low level parser error.

Answer (score 0):

It is like Benjamin Gruenenbaum commented. The error callback gets three parameters. The third one is the error:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "jsonp", 
     success: function (){       
     },
     error: function(xhr, opt, err){
         if(err instanceof SyntaxError){
         }
         if(err instanceof ReferenceError){
         }
     },
});
```

Comment: Not work for me. :( If I make console.log(err). The console.log show: "jQuery20204397698985412717_1396744296811 was not called".

Comment: You are right! I see the same thing with a cross-site request. (http://jsfiddle.net/2XcMd/) Before I was testing with both the HTML and the target on local disk (`file://`).   Perhaps it is a browser feature exactly devised to prevent this sort of information leak?